# how to save single quote in mysql database in php

Tags: php, mysql

I have the following error:

> Warning: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'batch will be conducted by Mr. Nitin Shende, /home/vinsysae/public_html/admin/private/mysql.php on line 251
>
> Warning: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'http://vinsys.in/wp-content/uploads/2013/04/pmi-banner-logo.png"> /home/vinsysae/public_html/admin/private/mysql.php on line 251
>
> Warning: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '>2) Group Discount :- Enroll for t' at line 2 in /home/vinsysae/public_html/admin/private/mysql.php on line

Comment: We need to see the query.

Comment: It's called `escaping` your strings, but if you were using bind variables with MySQLi or PDO, then you wouldn't need to worry about it

Comment: what's your code? if it's a string, you may want to scape them or encode them, such mysql_real_escape_string

Comment: http://tinyurl.com/klljwen

Comment: You can use [`addslashes()`](http://php.net/addslashes) on your string.

Comment: i am using ezmysql then how to save css code included single quote?

Comment: I had used adslashes() but it could not solve.

Answer (score 0):

You should use mysqli_real_escape_string to escape special characters in a string for use in an SQL statement http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.real-escape-string.php

Comment: is this possible to save single quote in mysql database with mysqli::real_escape_string?

Comment: Yes, that is what this mysqli_real_escape_string function is for. Try it out.